# Android app service memory usage difference between distinct versions

Tags: android, android-service, android-memory

I have an Android app that starts a service listening for incoming sms, and notifies the user with a pop up..

When I install and try the app in 2.3 android devices, it uses 4 to 5 mb of memmory, and trying on some devices from android 3.0 to 4.2 it uses 11 mb of memmory..

Can you explain why is this? or what can be the cause..?

Comment: Dump your heap and use MAT to determine where the memory is being consumed.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely what you're seeing is just the difference in how bitmaps are stored on 2.x vs 3.x-4.x.

On 2.x, Bitmaps were stored on the native memory and not the dalvik heap, so you can't actually properly measure them using Android Memory analysis tools (MAT, etc) since that only looks at the Dalvik Heap. See 2nd bullet point here : [Memory Management](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html)

On 3.x-4.x, the Bitmap memory is stored on the Dalvik Heap so it's easy to track with the usual memory tools. So your memory size on 3.x-4.x includes Bitmap memory that's not accounted for on the 2.3 side.

Without more information about your app, it's hard to say what else could cause this. There could be more overhead with 3.x/4.x devices which tend to have larger heaps than 2.x devices. Too many variables to speculate on. Honestly, as long as your app doesn't leak memory and memory doesn't grow exponentially, you shouldn't really concern yourself too much about the differences per platform.

Hope that helps.